# What is the default of the time transform function in the coxph command?

Tags: r, survival-analysis, cox-regression, cox

**Short introduction:**

A Cox Proportional Hazards (PH) model can be estimated with the `coxph` function of the `survival` package. An obvious requirement to get sensible results from this type of model is that the hazards are proportional, i.e., they are constant over time. If this is not the case for a certain variable, it can be solved by making the coefficient of this variable time varying. (Now it is technically an extended Cox model.) This is done by adding the `tt()` to that variable and specifying a function over time (see `vignette("timedep", package = "survival")` page 19+).

**Question:**

Which function is used if `tt()` is used without specifying a function?

Here is an example:

```
library(survival)
data(lung)
cox_model <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ age + sex + ph.karno, data = lung)
cox_model_ph <- cox.zph(cox_model) 
#              rho    chisq       p
# age      0.00701  0.00871 0.92566
# sex      0.12249  2.42336 0.11954
# ph.karno 0.23135  8.24167 0.00409
# GLOBAL        NA 11.54750 0.00911
```

We see that `ph.karno` violates the PH assumption (small p-value), so add `tt()`:

```
cox_model_tt <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ age + sex + tt(ph.karno), data = lung)
cox_model_tt_ph <- cox.zph(cox_model_tt)
#                   rho  chisq      p
# age          -0.00907 0.0142 0.9052
# sex           0.12844 2.7270 0.0987
# tt(ph.karno)  0.11643 2.3846 0.1225
# GLOBAL             NA 5.0220 0.1702
```

Now the PH assumption is satisfied, but I have no idea what the `tt()` function actually did. I tried some common used function such as `tt = function(x, t, ...) x*t`,  `tt = function(x, t, ...) x + t`, `tt = function(x, t, ...) x*log(t)`. But all gave different results (and were unable to fix the PH violation).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking through the code for `coxph` I think if I have found it. You offered no value for the 'tt'-parameter, so I think this gets executed:

```
if (is.null(tt)) {
            tt <- function(x, time, riskset, weights) {
                obrien <- function(x) {
                  r <- rank(x)
                  (r - 0.5)/(0.5 + length(r) - r)
                }
                unlist(tapply(x, riskset, obrien))
            }
```

And here's an experimental confirmation:

```
> cox_model_OB <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ age + sex + tt(ph.karno), data = lung, tt=  function(x, time, riskset, weights) {
+                 obrien <- function(x) {
+                   r <- rank(x)
+                   (r - 0.5)/(0.5 + length(r) - r)
+                 }
+                 unlist(tapply(x, riskset, obrien))
+             }
+ )
> ( cox_model_tt_ph <- cox.zph(cox_model_tt) )
                  rho  chisq      p
age          -0.00907 0.0142 0.9052
sex           0.12844 2.7270 0.0987
tt(ph.karno)  0.11643 2.3846 0.1225
GLOBAL             NA 5.0220 0.1702
```

<strike>I'm wondering if this was intentional. I suspect it is code left in during a development session. I suspect that Therneau intends that failure to offer a 'tt'-function should throw at least a warning, but probably would have preferred an error.</strike>
 So that was a guess and I found that I was wrong by searching through the vignettes and find that it is intended: "This relies on the fact that the input arguments to tt() are ordered by the event number or risk set. This function is used as a default if no tt argument is present in the coxph call, but there are tt terms in the model formula. (Doing so allowed me to depreciate the survobrien function)." ref: page 23 of "Using Time Dependent Covariates and Time Dependent Coefficients in the Cox Model"from the current survival package Index help page links to Vignettes.

Comment: in his vignette (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf, pg.19), Terry shows the difference between an incorrect time-transformation (e.g. using `I()`) and a correct time-transformation (e.g. using parameter `tt`).  Looking through the `coxph` source code (https://github.com/cran/survival/blob/master/R/coxph.R), I can see from a mathematical perspective what is going on with `tt`.  But can you elaborate on the conceptual reason why `tt` is required for a true time transformation?  Thank you.

Comment: I think your comment/question would be more appropriate for CrossValidated.com. I don't think it is really a coding question.

Comment: Gotcha. Will transfer over